# How polymorphism is working in the below code

Tags: java, null, overloading

Why is this code printing `String... null`?

```
class OverloadingTest {
            
    public void display(String ref){
        System.out.println("String..."+ref);
    }
            
    public void display(Object ref){
        System.out.println("Object..."+ref);
    }
            
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OverloadingTest test=new OverloadingTest();
        test.display(null);
                 
    }
}
```

Comment: That's how overloading works, it will take nearest specific data type when there's a conflict with Object and specific data type.

Comment: By the way, this has nothing to do with [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Or [maybe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Ad_hoc_polymorphism) it does?

Comment: @Olivier uh, first time I see it used in that context. You learn something new every day. (including learning to read the whole article when you link to it :P)

Answer (score -3):

1. Where's the polymorphism? The title says there is, but there's none in the code.
2. If you used a proper IDE or enabled warnings, you would get a warning, or depending on your warning settings, even a compile error, for the line `test.display(null);`, telling you that that call is ambiguous.
   And then you'd have to cast it to `test.display((String) null);` or `test.display((Object) null);`

### Update

Recent versions of Eclipse (using Eclipse Build) will NOT show the "ambiguous method call" warning anymore. The option to highlight those is missing in the Java Compiler section.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, above code compiles successfully. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. My answer is partially wrong, but not in a way you expect. The only thing wrong in my answer is that recent versions of Eclipse won't show the warning anymore.

Comment: overloading is compile time polymorphism.